# delete the last row in a table using sql query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete the last record in the table named **"marks"** in the database using **MySql query**.
The query I tried for this is as follows:

```
DELETE MAX(`id`) FROM `marks`;
```

There are 8 columns in the table. I want to delete the last column without specifying `id`, as in:

`DELETE FROM marks where id=8;`

After deleting the 8th record, I want to delete the 7th; after that 6th and so on, up to 1st record without specifying the `id` manually.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If `id` is auto-increment then you can use the following

```
delete from marks
order by id desc limit 1
```

Comment: exactly it works for me... thank you.... this is the exact thing i need... thank you again@Abhik Chakraborty

Comment: doesnt allow it in sql server?

Comment: @tichra the above query is specific to mysql however the same operation on sqlserver would be as `delete from marks where id in (select top 1 id from marks order by id desc )`

Answer (score 11):

@Abhshek's Answer is right and works for you but you can also try the following code if the id is not increment

```
DELETE FROM MARKS WHERE ID=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM MARKS)
```

Comment: Already I tried this logic. Its not working also, for not auto increment@Chintan7027

Comment: by this method what is result?

Comment: it returns nothing... displays this error ==> " #1093 - You can't specify target table 'marks' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: This LOGIC working for me.
I used = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE_SUB_CATEGORY+" WHERE "+ KEY_POSITION+"=(SELECT MAX("+KEY_POSITION+") FROM "+ TABLE_SUB_CATEGORY+" WHERE "+KEY_CAT_ID+ " = '"+cat_id+"' AND " +KEY_SUB_CAT_ID+ " = '"+scat_id+"')";

Comment: Can you explain that further? What do you mean by "if id is not increment"? What makes your query different to the one you are refering to?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best but a different solution.

```
DELETE FROM marks 
WHERE  id = (SELECT id 
             FROM   marks 
             ORDER  BY id DESC 
             LIMIT  1);
```

Comment: Should be noted that this answer only applies to MySql and not SqlServer or Oracle. In SQL Server, TOP 1 can be used after SELECT instead. In my case I wanted to remove the last 2 elements, so I used TOP 2 and used `IN` instead of `=`

Comment: This is deleting duplicate id as well instead of 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

This query uses a subquery to identify the MAX(row_id) for each group_id and
then deletes the rows matching both the group_id and the maximum row_id.

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE (group_id, row_id) IN (
    SELECT group_id, MAX(row_id)
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY group_id
);
```

Answer (score -1):

To delete 2nd Last Row

Delete from tablename where id in (select id from (select id  from tablename order by id desc limit 1,1) as id);

By using other queries it will show multiple errors.

Comment: Please `edit` to: 1) provide EXACT code necessary to solve the OP's issue, as specified in SO guidelines. You can read more in the help center linked to at the top of every page. `tablename` is not the name of the OP's table. 2) Edit to capitalize MySQL keywords, and 3) wrap code blocks in 3 backticks (or indent at least 4 spaces). 4) Please explain important bits of how/why your code solves the OP's issue, or explain how it differs from existing solutions, including any special circumstances it covers that other solutions may not. :-) Remember to upvote any existing good solutions.