# Conditionally delete last row in mysql

Tags: mysql

How do I conditionally delete the last row in a mysql table?

```
me/my_machine@17:26:57>cat create_tables.sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test_db;

USE test_db;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS err_hist_table (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  cl INT NOT NULL,
  usr VARCHAR(16),
  fault_code VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO err_hist_table (cl,usr,fault_code) VALUES (1,'pA','A'), (2,'pA','NULL'),(3,'pC','B'),(4,'pB','NULL');
```

The above SQL commands create a table that is like this:

```
MySQL [test_db]> SELECT * FROM err_hist_table;
+----+----+------+------------+
| id | cl | usr  | fault_code |
+----+----+------+------------+
|  1 |  1 | pA   | A          |
|  2 |  2 | pA   | NULL       |
|  3 |  3 | pC   | B          |
|  4 |  4 | pB   | NULL       |
+----+----+------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I want to `DELETE` the last row (biggest value of `id`) only when the value of `fault_code` is `NULL`. If it is not `NULL`, I want to skip the delete.
To my sql-newbie eyes, it seems like there should be a simple something like:

`SELECT * IF err_history_table.id=max(err_history_table) AND fault_code = 'NULL';`

I could not find my answer on the mysql docs page. Is there a simple solution for something like this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, what? If not, why not?

Comment: Probably already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32502830/7101876

Comment: Do you want to delete the row with the biggest value of `id` only if the `fault_code` is `NULL`?

Comment: Please write here what you have tried.

Comment: Crudely: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/661ef5/1 Note that it's more usual to store 'NULLs' as NULLs, in which case the comparison would be `WHERE x.fault_code IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a subquery that returns the row of the maximum `id` where you check the value of `fault_code`:

```
DELETE FROM err_hist_table
WHERE id = (
  SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT * FROM err_hist_table
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
  ) t
  WHERE fault_code IS NULL
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/of7pHRErCxSNMx19JZ5dtF/0).
Results:

```
| id  | cl  | usr | fault_code |
| --- | --- | --- | ---------- |
| 1   | 1   | pA  | A          |
| 2   | 2   | pA  |            |
| 3   | 3   | pC  | B          |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if this is what you want, but it should work. If you have a recent version of MySQL you should be able to use sub-queries, like this:

```
DELETE FROM err_hist_table WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM err_hist_table) AND fault_code IS NULL
```

Untested on your specific table of course. I would even suggest performing a SELECT first to verify it does what you expect.

Comment: you need to consider that during your request there can be inserted new row

Comment: In any big system this statement doesn't make any sense anyway, but technically you are true. You can surround it with a `LOCK TABLES err_hist_table WRITE` and `UNLOCK TABLES` make sure no writes can happen while this is executing. This is terrible for performance, but it can be done.

Comment: `WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM err_hist_table)` would never work in MySql. The error is: *You can't specify target table 'err_hist_table' for update in FROM clause*

Comment: Ok, so doing the select first and then the delete is actually needed. I didn't expect this to fail.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that you can acheive the desired result using a single `JOIN`, without needing a sub-sub-query and in a way which seems to me both concise and readable:

```
DELETE e1 FROM err_hist_table e1
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id
    FROM err_hist_table
) e2 USING (id)
WHERE e1.fault_code = 'NULL'
```

More on the topic of using joins in a `DELETE` statement here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html#idm45306662494864